# Express Checkout.js Recurring Payment

Tags: paypal, recurring

I am in the process of setting up an Express Checkout button which allows both one-time and recurring payments in one button. The single payments are working fine in the sandbox but I am running into problems when setting up billing agreement payments.

I am able to create a billing agreement which returns the JSON for the agreement, but then redirecting the flow to the login/payment screen doesn't work and shows an error message:
"Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

Before the error, the URL is:
"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?version=4&locale.x=en_GB&fundingSource=paypal&sessionID=5..."

So something is wrong when processing the request, but there are no errors returned in the console log.

Can anyone give some advice how to fix this please? Much appreciated